# PHP JSON Decode versus unserialize

Tags: php, json

I have the following result from geoPlugin http://www.geoplugin.net/json.gp?ip=64.90.182.55:

```
geoPlugin({
  "geoplugin_request":"64.90.182.55",
  "geoplugin_status":200,
  "geoplugin_city":"New York",
  "geoplugin_region":"NY",
  "geoplugin_areaCode":212,
  "geoplugin_dmaCode":501,
  "geoplugin_countryCode":"US",
  "geoplugin_countryName":"United States",
  "geoplugin_continentCode":"NA",
  "geoplugin_latitude":40.70890045166,
  "geoplugin_longitude":-74.001197814941,
  "geoplugin_regionCode":"NY",
  "geoplugin_regionName":"New York",
  "geoplugin_currencyCode":"USD",
  "geoplugin_currencySymbol":"&#36;",
  "geoplugin_currencyConverter":1
})
```

Is there a way to convert this into a PHP array? I don't want to use the PHP API of geoPlugin as it seems I need to use `unserialize`, which produces an E_WARNING on my development server (warnings are suppressed on production). I'd rather not have to deal with E_WARNINGs if I can. json_decode does not produce an E_WARNING on error, but it won't take the above output as valid.

Thoughts?

Comment: You should browse geoPlugin’s website more carefully: [webservices](http://www.geoplugin.com/webservices).

Comment: Gumbo is right,you should request `http://www.geoplugin.net/php.gp?ip=64.90.182.55` instead.then use `unserialize` function to decode the returns.

Comment: What warning are you getting from `unserialize()`?

Comment: Gumbo & Lake - I specifically do not want to use the PHP API, as stated in my original post, because of having to use `unserialize`.

Comment: lanzz - just unserialize('hello world') to see what I mean.

Comment: [The json is invalid](http://jsonlint.com/?json=http://www.geoplugin.net/json.gp?ip=64.90.182.55). Please tell which format that is.

Comment: @StackOverflowNewbie I very much doubt that geoPlugin's PHP API would return `'hello world'` to you.

Comment: @lanzz - right, it won't. But if you want to see the error unserialize returns when it gets something invalid, `"hello world"` will suffice.

Comment: @StackOverflowNewbie: Ah, well that's done with this PHP extension then: http://php.net/manual/en/book.v8js.php

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try removing the `geoPlugin()` surrounding the JSON then PHP's API should work.

You can remove it with [str_replace](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.str-replace.php) and [substr](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.substr.php).

An example is:

```
$json = str_replace("geoPlugin(", "", $original_json);
$json = substr($json, 0, -1);
$data = json_decode($json);
```

Comment: OK, I can do this via regex. Just was hoping there would be some native function in PHP that would do this for me ....

Answer (score 0):

As you could have easily validated with [jsonlint (demo)](http://jsonlint.com/?json=http://www.geoplugin.net/json.gp?ip=64.90.182.55) the json string you provided is not valid:

```
Parse error on line 1:
geoPlugin({    "geo
^
Expecting '{', '['
```

You should report this to the webservice you use, because it's not JSON so it looks misleading that this is called JSON API.

Also it's misleading that you expect the PHP `json_decode` function to work with a non-json string.

See http://json.org to learn more about json.

But next to all this, you wrote you already have the solution and you are just wondering. I hope this answer actually answers your (hidden) questions why that does not work.

Next time you should ask more directly what you're looking for ;) Hope this is helpful.

Comment: The API is returning JSONP (to get around the same origin policy). The geoPlugin() part is the padding. I was hoping for a was to convert it to an array using some native PHP function as I didn't want to deal with `unserialize` function.